# How to enable the submit button when the checkbox is checked with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

The form’s submit button should be disabled until the user has checked the checkbox to say that they have read and agree to the terms and conditions
Here is code html code for checkbox and submit button.I've tried this but failed

```js
var submit = document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0]; 
input.onchange=function() { 
    if(input.checked) { 
        document.getElementsByName('submit').disabled = false; 
    } else { 
        document.getElementsByName('submit').disabled = true; 
    } 
}
```

```html
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;" id='termsText'>I have read and agree to the terms and conditions <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book now!" disabled>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, it doesn't run until you submit the form.

Comment: I've tried this but failed

var submit = document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0];
input.onchange=function()
{
    if(input.checked)
    {
        document.getElementsByName('submit').disabled = false;
    }
    else
        {
            document.getElementsByName('submit').disabled = true;
        }
}

Comment: The first line should be `var input` not `var submit`.

Comment: You need `[0]` after `document.getElementsByName('submit')`, just like the other call to `getElementsByName`.

Comment: Your logic is correct, you just have these trivial errors.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it worked when add [0] after document.getElementsByName('submit') and even on var submit.

Answer (score 0):

**Here where you got it wrong :**

You put your checkbox reference to variable "submit". Then you used another variable named "input" where there is no value in it.

**Updated Answer :**

```html
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;" id='termsText'>I have read and agree to the terms and conditions <input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book now!" disabled>
<script>
    var input = document.getElementsByName('termsChkbx')[0];
    var submit = document.getElementsByName('submit')[0];
    input.onchange=function() {
        if(input.checked) {
            submit.disabled = false;
        } else {
            submit.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The thing is I'm not allowed to edit html code, every thing should be done with using javascript

Comment: hi @Gokul this is now updated. I also mentioned above where you got it wrong